# Where f(n) = n! belongs to? P, co-P, NPComplete or NPHard?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np, factorial

Where  f(n) = n! belongs to? P, co-P, NPComplete or NPHard?

Comment: do you define $f(n)$ as a complexity function? what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Have a look at the definitions. As a starter, is "f(n) = n!" a decision problem?

Comment: A decision problem would be "given n and x, is n! = x?" How much time would it take you to decide that? In the non-decision problem "Given n, what is n! in decimal notation", how large would be the output, compared to the size of the input? Can that problem be solved in polynomial time?